# Sendkeys Is not working as expected. Unable to send data using sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium, appium

SendKeys is not working in appium. It is giving an error like Element is not located but element can be located easily in the script.
Here is the code:

```
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import javax.swing.Action;

    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

    public class Testcase extends AppiumTest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
{
     AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=Capabilities();
    // Thread.sleep(20000);
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
     
     driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index='5']").click(); 
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']").click(); \\ **same xpath for click it working fine but after send the data using sendkeys it shows error**
     driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']").sendKeys("Abc");
```

Comment: please add stack trace in the question.

Comment: `.implicitlyWait()` doesn't work like that. It doesn't wait when you call it, it's a one-time set of the timeout and lasts the life of the driver.